# 3D nonogram – What's going on?

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

This is a **three-dimensional nonogram**. The first six squares depict the layers of a $6\times6\times6$ cube. The final square gives the enumerations for the Z-axis, top to bottom. Some rules:

- The grid has five different colours: Red, blue, green, orange and purple. The black numbers can refer to stretches of any colour, whereas coloured numbers are always the same colour of the squares they refer to. Cells filled with different colours do not need to have a gap between them (that is, "1 1" can refer to one red cell and one blue cell which are adjacent to one another).
- If a row or column has no numbers, that means that the composition of that row/column is **unknown**. Note that this is different than the usual practice in nonograms where a missing number means that the row/column has no coloured cells at all. In our case, such rows can be explicitly marked with a zero.
- The Z-axis enumerations are all single digits, so e.g. 11 means two stretches of one, not one stretch of eleven. Similarly, "4x1" means four stretches of one.

> [image]
>   ([Colourblind-friendly version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaZ7o.png))

Can you guess what is going on? What would you recommend next?

Comment: does a 3 mean 3 continuous blocks of same or different color(s)? thanks

Comment: @OmegaKrypton One number is always a certain number of continuous cells *of the same colour*.

Comment: ok thanks... not an expert at monograms...

Comment: Is the Z view listed from top down or from the bottom up?

Comment: @Bass Top to bottom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The completed nonogram is:

> [image]

Which appears to be

> a 3D tetris game. Each colour represents a type of tetronimo.

In 3D the view looks like -

Blue:

> [image]

Orange:

> [image]

Green:

> [image]

Purple:

> [image]

Red:

> [image]

All together:

> [image]

I would recommend

> Dropping the top piece into the pink highlighted area.
>  [image]

Comment: what software did you use for the 3d diagrams? thanks +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton that looks like a screenshot from Blender.

Comment: Yep, it's Blender

Comment: This is the intended answer. There seems to be something a bit off in the 3D representation, though? There's a gap near the bottom right corner.

Comment: I have fixed the 3D view and made it a bit more clear what is happening.